# Application Role connect to SQL Server with "Login Failed" error

Tags: .net, sql-server, winforms

I have a program which would use the Application Role to write data to a SQL Server 2005.

```
using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
   SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
   sqlCommand.Connection = sqlCon;
   sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
   sqlCommand.CommandText = "";
   sqlCommand.CommandText = "EXEC sp_setapprole 'name','password';";
   sqlCommand.CommandText += sqlComm;
   sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 300;
   sqlCon.Open();

   int res = sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

I use this code to connect a SQL Server 2005 ServerA, it works well. Then I use the same code to connect anohter SQL Server 2005 ServerB, with the identical table, application role, it gave an error."Login Failed for domain\username" Does anyone meet it before?

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException was
>   unhandled by user code
>   Message="Login failed for user
>   'domian\username'."   Source=".Net
>   SqlClient Data Provider"
>   ErrorCode=-2146232060   Class=14
>   LineNumber=65536   Number=18456
>   Procedure=""   Server="ServerB"
>   State=1
>   StackTrace:
>     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection)
>     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj)
>     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior
>   runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler,
>   SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet
>   bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj)
>     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean
>   enlistOK)
>     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, String newPassword,
>   Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64
>   timerExpire, SqlConnection
>   owningObject)
>     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(String
>   host, String newPassword, Boolean
>   redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection
>   owningObject, SqlConnectionString
>   connectionOptions, Int64 timerStart)
>     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection
>   owningObject, SqlConnectionString
>   connectionOptions, String newPassword,
>   Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
>     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString
>   connectionOptions, Object
>   providerInfo, String newPassword,
>   SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean
>   redirectedUserInstance)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection
>   owningConnection)
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection,
>   DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup)
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection)
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory
>   connectionFactory)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
>      at ADSK.PSEB.ACRSubmitComponent.ACRSubmit.backgroundUploadWork_DoWork(Object
>   sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) in
>   C:\Documents and
>   Settings\lvlu\Desktop\Mulder\Upload\ADSK.PSEB.ACRSubmitComponent\trunk\ADSK.PSEB.ACRSubmitComponent\Form1.cs:line
>   897
>      at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs
>   e)
>      at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object
>   argument)

Answer (score 3):

The error message really says it all:

```
SqlException was unhandled by user code 
Message="Login failed for user 'domain\username'." 
Source=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" ErrorCode=-2146232060 Class=14
```

From this, you should see that the user the you use to connect to your ServerB does not have an account on that second server, obviously.

It has nothing to do with your application role or whatever - your user "domain\username" just simply doesn't have access rights to the second server.

Add a login for that user, and grant him access and the necessary permissions on the databases needed, and you should be fine.

Marc

Answer (score 1):

maybe there is something wrong with your connectionstrings

the format of the connectionstring is like:

`<add name="dbconnect" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=db_name;User ID=sa;Password=....." providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

reference website: [Connection problems with SQL Server in ASP.NET applications using out-of-process session state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/810673/connection-problems-with-sql-server-in-asp-net-applications-using-out-of-process)