# Entity Framework Query Timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

In my controller I have the following code:

```
    public ActionResult Syslogs(string IPAddress) {
        IEnumerable<Syslogd> syslogs = db.Syslogds.Take(100).ToList();

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(IPAddress)) {
            syslogs = db.Syslogds.Where(s => s.MsgHostname == IPAddress).Take(100).ToList();
        }

        return View(syslogs.ToList());
    }
```

The query times out whenever I pass a certain value to the `IPAddress` variable. I'm not sure why that is happening or how I can prevent it. Does the value not exist in the database or is it just taking a long time to find it? Here is the error message I receive:

> An exception of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: An error occurred while executing the command
>   definition. See the inner exception for details.

The inner exception:

> {"Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of
>   the operation or the server is not responding."}

Comment: On a side note, you are always executing the first query even if you are overwriting those values with a filter on IP. You should move the first query to the else clause to avoid doing any extra unnecessary work.

Comment: How many records does Syslogd have? Is the database on a separate machine? What is network bandwidth usage?

Answer (score 3):

It's possible that the value doesn't exist, but a Timeout just means that the query didn't complete in the time given for the command to execute.  I *think* the default timeout for EF is 30 seconds for commands.

Basic question, but, if your Syslogd table has many records, is there an index on MsgHostname?

Comment: I have discovered that the record just doesn't exist in the database. I guess my question now is how can I check for that before executing the query? I have tried db.Syslogd.Any() but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

As Ryan said default timeout for EF is 30 seconds for commands . So you can increase the execution timeout time.

By using [CommandTimeOut](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.commandtimeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
    // Specify a timeout for queries in this context, in seconds.
    context.CommandTimeout = 120;
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11748231)

Or by using [Database.CommandTimeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.database.commandtimeout?view=entity-framework-6.2.0)

```
// or for all object in context (in seconds)
context.Database.CommandTimeout = 120;
```

**Consider this also:**

1. Moreover you are using `.ToList()` which is forcing immediate query execution and I think you can avoid that to improve the performance.
2. `IEnumerable` is suitable for querying data from in-memory collections like List, Array etc, but it's not suitable for querying data from out-memory (like remote database, service) collections and paging.

So I strongly recommend to use `IQueryable` in this case.

Reference
[codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/732425/IEnumerable-Vs-IQueryable)

[IQueryable Vs. IEnumerable in terms of LINQ to SQL queries](http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/iqueryable-vs-ienumerable)